# Terminology of different number representations

Tags: terminology

### Background:

I am writing an article and trying to find the proper words/terms for different representations of numbers. The article is regarding calculating the SIN, COS and TAN of a number of angles without getting decimal numbers because the "other" form is better for calculations when these are used in other formulas.

Here are two examples:

Two square roots of two can be written in the following two ways:

First:
$$
2\sqrt 2 
$$

Second (floating point/decimal):
$$
2.82842712475
$$

### Question

The second example is a decimal number.

What is the name for the representation of two square root of two in the first example?

Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, "simplest radical form" also seems to be an answer.

Comment: One should note that 2\sqrt 2 \neq 2.82842712475$.

Comment: Another form: $\sqrt{8}$

Answer (score 4):

When we write $2\sqrt{2}$ it's simply referred to the **exact** form.

Comment: Another option would be "symbolic".

Comment: Thanks Sean! This is the google search I needed! :) Just to add to this, a few definitions I read of "exact form" were that an "exact number" has a certain value, it cannot be simplified, and there are an infinite amount of significant digits.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the values of trigonometric functions that can be expressed symbolically, what you have is an *algebraic* expression (also called *radical*), which is a special case of a *closed-form* expression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Comparison_of_different_classes_of_expressions